# package.json file for meteor.js?

Tags: node.js, meteor

Is there a simple npm style way to build a package.json file for meteor.js?   Or something similar so I can upload files to github without all the packages and someone can easily run a command to re-download all the attached required packages?

I downloaded some meteor files and saw that the .meteor folder was not there, so I could not view the packages file to even do it manually.

How is this handled in meteor?

Comment: take a look here http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Packaging_existing_Libraries

Comment: Are you saying that you have a Meteor project without the .meteor folder and you are looking for a way to generate it?

Comment: That would be great, but I'm not sure how that could be possible?  I usually just run `meteor create`, then place the project files into that folder. Is there a better way to do it?   

But no, I'm actually asking how to find and relink dependent packages, like like the package.json functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can .gitignore .meteor/local (the plugin cache is where your Meteor packages are).  If someone clones your repo, the first time they run the meteor project all the dependences will install.